# session data not passing using CURL in php

Tags: php, curl

Below is the CURL call I am using in my php file

```
$url=$path."l2pharmaserviceclassfile.php?action=PENDINGDRUGORDERS&session_id1=".$_SESSION['sessionid']."&pop_id=".$_SESSION['popId']."&user_id=".$_SESSION['userId'];   
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);          
    $result = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);    
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

This is what I have written in l2pharmaserviceclassfile.php

```
else if($_REQUEST['action']=='PENDINGDRUGORDERS')
{   
    echo $_REQUEST['session_id1'];
}
```

But I am unable to get the session id value. when I try `echo $_REQUEST['pop_id'];` I am getting the value.

Comment: Have you started session using `session_start();` in your PHP script?

Comment: Judging by the other values, you have probably stored your value with the key `sessionId` and not `sessionid`.

Comment: How'd you define `$_SESSION['sessionid']` on the other code?

Comment: I have started with session and can able to see value in the php file where from I am passing the session value.

Answer (score 2):

A session id may contain special characters that need to be encoded to be sent in a query string.
Probably is better to rely on PHP core functions for this kind of stuff:

```
$parameters = array(
  'action'      => 'PENDINGDRUGORDERS',
  'session_id1' => $_SESSION['sessionid'],
  'pop_id'      => $_SESSION['popId'],
  'user_id'     => $_SESSION['userId']
);

$url = sprintf(
  "%s?%s",
  $path."l2pharmaserviceclassfile.php",
  http_build_query($parameters)
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);          
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```